# Getting data on click from api

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I get some data out of an API. I make two calls to the API and save this output in a variable. Now I have two links - One for `Data1` and one for `Data2`. If I click on `Data1`, the first call should be loaded. Click on `Data2` shows the second call should take place. When someone visits the site, `Data1` should be the default displayed dataset.

I have a nearly working solution:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function(){
                $("#data1").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var datasets = document.getElementById("datasets");
                    var html = '';
                    var i = 0;
                    var results = <?php echo json_encode($resultsD1) ?>;
                    for (const result of results) {
                        html += '<article class="dataset"><span class="title">' + result["title"] + '</span><div class="data-meta">';
                        html += '<span class="release">' + result["release"] + '</span></div></article>';
                        i++;
                    }
                    products.innerHTML = html;
                });
                $("#data2").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var datasets = document.getElementById("datasets");
                    var html = '';
                    var i = 0;
                    var results = <?php echo json_encode($resultsD2) ?>;
                    for (const result of results) {
                        html += '<article class="dataset"><span class="title">' + result["title"] + '</span><div class="data-meta">';
                        html += '<span class="release">' + result["release"] + '</span></div></article>';
                        i++;
                    }
                    products.innerHTML = html;
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Now if I click on `Data1` the correct data is loaded. The same when I click on `Data2`. But how can I make `Data1` as default when the site is loaded? Also my code seems so bad constructed. I repeat the whole for loop two times...

Comment: [Trigger the click event (after you've defined it)](https://learn.jquery.com/events/triggering-event-handlers/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
    function setData(dataset_type){
        var html = '';
                    var i = 0;
        var products = document.getElementById("datasets");
                    var results = <?php echo json_encode($resultsD1) ?>;
        if(dataset_type == 2){
            results = <?php echo json_encode($resultsD2) ?>;
        }
                    for (const result of results) {
                        html += '<article class="dataset"><span class="title">' + result["title"] + '</span><div class="data-meta">';
                        html += '<span class="release">' + result["release"] + '</span></div></article>';
                        i++;
                    }
                    products.innerHTML = html;
    }

    // Default Call onload for dataset 1
    setData(1);

            $("#data1").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                setData(1);
            });
            $("#data2").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                setData(2);
            });     
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that answers which explain code are upvoted more often and downvoted less often than code without. Stack Overflow answers are meant to help everyone with similar questions, not just the OP. See [answer]. Thanks for contributing.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Simple and easy to understand. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the logic to load the data in function, and call the function on button click as well as on page load.
As per your code, as soon as button is clicked the new data is replacing your old data, do you want to do that or you want to keep old data as it is and append new data? I have added comments in the script as answered for above question

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        
        function loadData(){
        var datasets = document.getElementById("datasets");
                    var html = '';
                    var i = 0;
                    var results = <?php echo json_encode($resultsD1) ?>;
                    for (const result of results) {
                        html += '<article class="dataset"><span class="title">' + result["title"] + '</span><div class="data-meta">';
                        html += '<span class="release">' + result["release"] + '</span></div></article>';
                        i++;
                    }
                    //products.append(html); // if you want to append data uncomment this and comment below
                    products.innerHTML = html; // if you want to replace data comment this and uncomment above
}
        
            $(function(){

// function call on page load
loadData();

                $("#data1").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    loadData();
                });
                $("#data2").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var datasets = document.getElementById("datasets");
                    var html = '';
                    var i = 0;
                    var results = <?php echo json_encode($resultsD2) ?>;
                    for (const result of results) {
                        html += '<article class="dataset"><span class="title">' + result["title"] + '</span><div class="data-meta">';
                        html += '<span class="release">' + result["release"] + '</span></div></article>';
                        i++;
                    }
                    products.innerHTML = html;
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: It would be better to pass the data to load to the `loadData` function, wouldn't it? So that it could be used for both event handlers/

Comment: yes, there is always scope of improvement, the intention was to guide person about using the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function

```
var datasets =document.getElementById("datasets");// make it global
$( window ).load(function() {

       loadData(whichButtonCliked,datasets )
});

loadData(whichButtonCliked,datasets )
{
 e.preventDefault();

                    var html = '';
                    var i = 0;
                    var results = <?php echo json_encode($resultsD2) ?>;
                    for (const result of results) {
                        html += '<article class="dataset"><span class="title">' + result["title"] + '</span><div class="data-meta">';
                        html += '<span class="release">' + result["release"] + '</span></div></article>';
                        i++;
                    }
                    products.innerHTML = html;
}
```

and call this function on click now you have to make condition which button is clicked